# .trigger(click) not automatically clicking the link on doc ready

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get jQuery to click a link for me on document ready, but it is not working. It locates the link correctly when run in the console, but does not navigate to the page.

The code I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.portallink a').trigger('click', function() {
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       $(location).attr('href', href)
   });
});
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class='portallink'>
        <a href="www.thelocation.com">Link</font></a>
        <span class="sitsnewcoptext"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a mixture of a click handler and a trigger call, neither of which are correct.

If you want to trigger the link click automatically on page load, use `trigger('click')` with no handler function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.portallink a').trigger('click');
});
```

You should also note that your link needs `http://` in front of it as it's going to an external site. Currently it will be used as a relative path and will most likely end up in a 404 error.

Comment: Ya but clicking on anchor is especially discarded in jQuery, this would work instead, using native DOM click method: `$('.portallink a')[0].click();`

Comment: @A.Wolff I agree. The code itself doesn't make much sense. I'm just trying to at least solve the immediate issues :)

Comment: Indeed, the OP's code doesn't make sense, i didn't carefully read it

Answer (score 0):

Just separate trigger and click event:

```
$('.portallink a').click(function() {
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(location).attr('href', href )
})

$('.portallink a').click(); // trigger this event after click event initialized
```

Comment: `$(location).attr('href', href)` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.portallink a')[0].click();
    })
```

below is the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/csz0ggsw/6/